# PostgreSQL: Upgrade from 8.4.2 to 9.0.3 not working

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I am working on application that uses PostgreSQL. Until now everything was finde until we have upgraded PostgreSQL version from 8.4.2 to 9.0.3.
Statement `SelectLastChangedColumn(parameter)` no longer works.

The log file does not give any information.

Using old ODBC driver fixed the error but it is not satisfactional resolution.

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Why are you upgrading to an outdated version? The latest 9.0 release is 9.0.19. If you are upgrading to a version that is going to be unsupported in 6 months, then at least use the latest minor release

Comment: As 9.0.3 is an old version of PostgreSQL it may be logical that an old ODBC driver works, so if you want to use a newer ODBC driver try the last PostgreSQL stable version AKA 9.4

Comment: I am sorry guys. I made a typo. The upgrade went from 8.4.2 to 9.3.3. I found a soulition for my problem. Parametr's `UseServerSidePrepare` default value has been changed from `0` to `1` since 9.3 release.